# XSL "if" statement to not display an element if it is not present

Tags: xslt, rss

I am developing an RSS manager and various RSS feeds will contain various elements, some may not include these elements. I would like to implement an xsl:if statement to not display an element if it does not exist in the feed.

For example:

```
<xsl:template match="item"> <!--an item in a feed-->
<xsl:value-of select="title" /> <!--display feed items title-->

<xsl:value-of select="author" />    <!--to display item's author BUT not all feed items have an author-->
```

How can I make it so that it does not display author info unless that element is present?

Comment: Apparently you can use - <xsl:if test> etc - But I do not understand how to test the condition.

Comment: Please provide a source XML! I would use something like this <xsl:template match="item/author"> to match the items that have an author and save the <xsl:if>. Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the standard recursive-descent style of XSLT coding, then

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="author"/>
```

achieves the required effect: if there is no author, nothing is output.

Answer (score 2):

XSL never complains about existance of node, in simple words **Do it only if the node is present** is taken care by-default.

In the above code, it tries to find `<author>` node, if found it will copy else ignore.

If you are worried about unnecessary whitespace then use this: (assuming that current node is parent of author)

```
<xsl:if test='author'>
    <xsl:value-of select="author" />
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

<xsl:apply-templates select="item[title]"> will use the "item" template only if it conains a "title" element.
@Peter: item/author will not match item with author child but author with item parent
@AlexM: I would prefer not to mimic procedural programming and use the XSLT way instead

Comment: I think he is more concerned about if an item has an author or not. That is why I requested a source XML. Without that it is mostly just guessing around.